# Upgrade openSUSE 13.1 server to 13.2 or Evergreen?

Tags: upgrade, opensuse

I am running openSUSE 13.1 server on a VPS with a few services:

- Nginx
- MySQL (Maria DB)
- Tomcat with Oracle JDK 1.7
- SVN server

Since 13.2 is already out, 13.1 support will come to EOL some time this year.
13.1 was selected to be supported by the [Evergreen project](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Evergreen#Evergreen) starting in May 2015.

What would be a preferred strategy of upgrade here?

1. Upgrade the server to 13.2 and subsequently to every main release version in future, which possibly brings a risk that the VPS will not reboot after the upgrade.
2. Switch to the 13.1 Evergreen repo, which will end its support in November 2016. In this case, I haven't found any additional info on if and how an Evergreen system can be further upgraded to the next Evegreen or main release.

Thank you for any help / experience share!